# RegEx for a Glossary Function

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm working on a web-based help system that will auto-insert links into the explanatory text, taking users to other topics in help. I have hundreds of terms that should be linked, i.e.

"Manuals and labels" (describes these concepts in general)
"Delete Manuals and Labels" (describes this specific action)
"Learn more about adding manuals and labels" (again, more specific action)

I have a RegEx to find / replace whole words (good ol' \b), which works great, except for linked terms found inside other linked terms. Instead of:

```
<a href="#">Learn more about manuals and labels</a>
```

I end up with

```
<a href="#">Learn more about <a href="#">manuals and labels</a></a>
```

Which makes everyone cry a little. Changing the order in which the terms are replaced (going shortest to longest) means that I''d get:

```
Learn more about <a href="#">manuals and labels</a>
```

Without the outer link I really need.

The further complication is that the capitalization of the search terms can vary, and I need to retain the original capitalization. If I could do something like this, I'd be all set:

```
Regex _regex = new Regex("\\b" + termToFind + "(|s)" + "\\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

string resultingText = _regex.Replace(textThatNeedsLinksInserted, "<a>" + "$&".Replace(" ", "_") + "</a>));
```

And then after all the terms are done, remove the "_", that would be perfect. "Learn_more_about_manuals_and_labels" wouldn't match "manuals and labels," and all is well.

It would be hard to have the help authors delimit the terms that need to be replaced when writing the text -- they're not used to coding. Also, this would limit the flexibility to add new terms later, since we'd have to go back and add delimiters to all the previously written text.

Is there a RegEx that would let me replace whitespace with "_" in the original match? Or is there a different solution that's eluding me?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "linked terms" and show a complete example of what `termToFind` and `textThatNeedsLinksInserted` represent? It would help to see a before and after example too.

Comment: termToFind would be "Learn more about manuals and labels", "manuals and labels", "Delete Manuals and Labels".

Comment: textThatNeedsLinksInserted could be "Having trouble with your manuals and labels? Learn more about adding manuals and labels. Need to get rid of them? Try to delete manuals and labels."

Comment: And the ideal result would be: `Having trouble with your <a href="1.html">manuals and labels</a>? <a href="2.html">Learn more about adding manuals and labels</a>. Need to get rid of them? Try to <a href="3.html">delete manuals and labels</a>.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your examples with nested links it sounds like you're making individual passes over the terms and performing multiple `Regex.Replace` calls. Since you're using a regex you should let it do the heavy lifting and put a nice pattern together that makes use of alternation.

In other words, you likely want a pattern like this: `\b(term1|term2|termN)\b`

```
var input = "Having trouble with your manuals and labels? Learn more about adding manuals and labels. Need to get rid of them? Try to delete manuals and labels.";
var terms = new[] 
{
    "Learn more about adding manuals and labels",
    "Delete Manuals and Labels",
    "manuals and labels"
};

var pattern = @"\b(" + String.Join("|", terms) + @")\b";
var replacement = @"<a href=""#"">$1</a>";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Now, to address the issue of a corresponding href value for each term, you can use a dictionary and change the regex to use a `MatchEvaluator` that will return the custom format and look up the value from the dictionary. The dictionary also ignores case by passing in `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`. I tweaked the pattern slightly by adding `?:` at the start of the group to make it a non-capturing group since I am no longer referring to the captured item as I did in the first example.

```
var terms = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    { "Learn more about adding manuals and labels", "2.html" },
    { "Delete Manuals and Labels", "3.html" },
    { "manuals and labels", "1.html" }
};

var pattern = @"\b(?:" + String.Join("|", terms.Select(t => t.Key)) + @")\b";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern,
    m => String.Format(@"<a href=""{0}"">{1}</a>", terms[m.Value], m.Value),
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Aha! I really like that. The only trouble is that from your example the surrounding text would be the same, no matter what the term was that matched. And if I wanted the href to be 1.html for the first term, 2.html for the second term, etc. could I do an additional capture group that has the destination htmls for each term (in the same order as the terms themselves?)

Comment: @TimWestover I was just working on that! I updated my answer to show how you can use a dictionary and a `MatchEvaluator` in the `Regex.Replace` call to look up the appropriate value.

Comment: that's perfect. Works like a charm. I tweaked it just a little to support a simple plural (an extra s) as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an ordered dictionary like this, making sure the smallest term is last:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        OrderedDictionary Links = new OrderedDictionary();
        Links.Add("Learn more about adding manuals and labels", "2");
        Links.Add("Delete Manuals and Labels", "3");
        Links.Add("manuals and labels", "1");

        string text = "Having trouble with your manuals and labels? Learn more about adding manuals and labels. Need to get rid of them? Try to delete manuals and labels.";

        foreach (string termToFind in Links.Keys)
        {
            Regex _regex = new Regex(@"\b" + termToFind + @"s?\b(?![^<>]*</)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            text = _regex.Replace(text, @"<a href=""" + Links[termToFind] + @".html"">$&</a>");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/gaOHLP)

The negative lookahead (`(?![^<>]*</)`) I added prevents the replace of a part you already replaced before which is between anchor tags.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can prevent your Regex for `manuals and labels` from finding `Learn more about manuals and labels` by using a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Modified your regex looks like this:

```
(?<!Learn more about )(manuals and labels)
```

But for your specific request i would suggest a different solution. You should define a rule or priority list for your regexs or both. A possible rule could be "always search for the regex first that matches the most characters". This however requires that your regexs are always fixed length. And it does not prevent one regex from consuming and replacing characters that would have been matched by a different regex (maybe even of the same size).

Of course you will need to add an additional lookbehind and lookahead to each of your regexs to prevent replacing strings that are inside of your replacing elements